# Silverlight on Windows Phone: IValueConverter is never called for a custom bound property

Tags: c#, silverlight, binding

I have a user control with a property defined as follows:

```
public partial class ChartEx : UserControl
{
    private object _dataSource;

    public object DataSource
    {
        get { return _dataSource; }
        set 
        { 
            _dataSource = value; //break here
        }
    }

}
```

In my xaml, I'm trying to bind it to a collection (from inside data template):

```xml
<DataTemplate x:Key="tmplCounter">
    <my:ChartEx 
             DataContext="{Binding Converter={StaticResource convTest}, ConverterParameter='DataContext'}"
             DataSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource convTest}, ConverterParameter='DataSource'}">
    </my:ChartEx>
</DataTemplate>
```

But in debugger I see that value that comes to DataSource setter is of type System.Windows.Data.Binding!

Value converter is *never* entered with parameter "DataSource", but for "DataContext" it works perfectly. Converter is there merely for debugging purposes, without it things work same way.

How do I make Binding work for properties I defined?

Comment: I don't think I understand exactly what you're trying to accomplish here. Why do you need to call converter twice? Once in DataContext and once in DataSource?

Comment: I want to call it in DataSource and get the value.
DataContext is there just to show that same exact markup works for an inherited property

Comment: What you are doing in DataSource is you are calling the setter of it by calling a method that would pass the getter of it. Are you trying to pass the DataContext of the chart as parameter to the converter method? Can you post a code of the scenario that doesn't work, along with the converter signature? Why are you trying to convert the datacontext by passing the datacontext?

Comment: That converter does nothing, I'm just using it to monitor if Binding happens.

Comment: In the XAML - _dataSource field gets assigned a weird value of type System.Windows.Data.Binding.
I've just figured it out, will close the question soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, sorry all, I'm a moron.
Turns out in XAML you can't bind to "simple" properties. The prop must be a dependency property. Following works:

```
public partial class ChartEx : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler DataSourceChanged;

    public object DataSource
    {
        get { return GetValue(DataSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "DataSource",
            typeof(object),
            typeof(ChartEx),
            new PropertyMetadata(true, OnDataSourcePropertyChanged));

    private static void OnDataSourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ChartEx source = d as ChartEx;

        if (source.DataSourceChanged != null)
            source.DataSourceChanged(source, new EventArgs());
    }
```